# Connection fails: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, loopbackjs, nodemon

I am using Loopback with MySql. I am getting following error randomly when I run

```
nodemon .
```

or

```
node .
```

> ```
> Web server listening at: http://0.0.0.0:3000
> Browse your REST API at http://0.0.0.0:3000/explorer
> Connection fails: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
> It will be retried for the next request.
> events.js:160
>       throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
>       ^
>
> Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
>     at PoolConnection.Connection._handleConnectTimeout
> ```

1. How should I fix this issue? On Loopback side configuration or MySQL
   configuration? NOTE: I am using MAMP for MySQL.
2. It takes lot of time to start successfully without error. What
   should I do to fast restart?

Comment: Showing some code would make it easier for us to help

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a known issue with MySQL and Loopback that causes the connection to time out under heavy load when Loopback is first starting:

https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-connector-mysql/issues/210

A few possible solutions:

- If you're running on a VM or container, increasing the CPU resources may fix the issue.
- Set `connectTimeout` and `acquireTimeout` in the datasource configuration (adjust the values as needed):

  ```json
  {
  "mySQL":{
      //...
      "connectTimeout": 20000,
      "acquireTimeout": 20000
  }
  ```

  (https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-connector-mysql/issues/210#issuecomment-258089303)
- Here's another option:

  > Our solution was to remove the initial database connection from the loopback boot by enabling lazyConnect in the datasource config, and then to separately call the datasource connection after the boot is finished. We came to a similar conclusion that CPU stress during the loopback boot causes the db connection to fail.

  (https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-connector-mysql/issues/210#issuecomment-758091028)

Answer (score 0):

The most probable cause might be that some other service is using the **same port**,  change the port.

I had similar issue with nodemon not with node though, because of not having *system32 folder in my path variable*.

Comment: Unfortunately this can't be the solution because the asker mentioned that they were getting the error "randomly." Also, the timeout error in question is caused by the MySQL loopback connector trying to connect to the database. If another service was running on the same port, you would instead see an error such as `Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::3000`